# SQL Server - Get result from one row into another

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

In our sales system discount is added in the end but when moving this data to another system I need the discount in every line.

In this case there are three groups and they are separetaed with LineType 2 and 64.  In the first group I need to get result from Forumula_discount = 15 line ID 972922 into four lines above and then also in the other groups.

Can you guide me in how it is best to solve this in Select statement on SQL server.

[image: My result now]

Regards,
BG

Comment: Please post results in Text.  Also provide table structure of tables (not just results) and provide desired results.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the groups, which I think you can do with a cumulative sum.  Then use window functions to "spread" the value:

```
select t.*,
       sum(formula_discount) over (partition by docno, grp) as imputed_formula_discount
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when linetype in (2, 64) then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by docno order by id) as grp
      from t
     ) t;
```

Answer (score 0):

What you really need here are 2 views into the same table.  One view would represent products and the other discounts.  This is typical of old school systems.  You can then join the 2 different views of the table to each other based on the line type.  Instead of creating actual database views, I'll simply use a self join.  I'll alias the table twice... p to represent the products and d to represent discounts.

Basically, 'products' have a line type of 1 and discounts are 64.  You never mentioned the name of the table, but I'll call it 'dbtable' for this example.  Try this.

```
select p.docno, p.id, p.linetype, p.type, p.item_NO, d.formula_discount
from dbtable p inner join dbtable d
  on p.linetype = d.linetype
  and d.linetype = 64 -- This limits 'd' rows to just discounts
where p.linetype = 1;
```

Note you could actually define database views for each to make it more concrete for you.